# Dynamically Loading Markdown Files in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I am trying to use `mdsvex` to create a markdown blog.  I have installed the package using `npx svelte-add@latest mdsvex`.  I then create a `[slug].svelte` file so that I can test if it works:

```
// src/routes/posts/[slug].svelte

<script context="module">
    export async function load({ page }) {
        const Hello = (await import('../../posts/hello.md')).default;

        return {
            props: { Hello }
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let Hello;
</script>


<Hello />
```

This works exactly as I want it to work.  If I navigate to `localhost:3000/posts/hello`, it loads up the `src/posts/hello.md` file and displays it properly.

Now I want to make the `[slug].svelte` file dynamic.  So I change it as follows:

```
// src/routes/posts/[slug].svelte

<script context="module">
    export async function load({ page }) {
        const Post = (await import(`../../posts/${page.params.slug}.md`)).default;

        return {
            props: { Post }
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let Post;
</script>

<Post />
```

This, however, does NOT work.  I get the following error if I refresh the `localhost:3000/posts/hello` page:

```
failed to load module for ssr: posts/hello.md

Error: failed to load module for ssr: posts/hello.md
    at instantiateModule (C:\code\learn\svelte\blog-2\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-f2b4ca46.js:73353:15)
```

Any idea why this does not work and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think dynamic imports using slugs is supported in SvelteKit yet(I could be wrong) since I've had issues with using dynamic imports and haven't found any solution yet. I'd suggest rendering your component in Server Side instead of sending it as prop to see if it fixes your issue:
https://svelte.dev/docs#Server-side_component_API

Comment: I believe [slug].svelte code is run on the client but the load function you intend to run has to run on the server in order to access the params prop. Move the function inside +page.js(ts).